# PHP: Generator over foreach

Tags: php

So i have rather big array I need to iterate over. Here is conventional way:

```
foreach ($rows as $csvRow) {
    // do something with $csvRow
}
```

But then I thought of using Generator because as they say it doesn't consume much memory:

```
$getRow = function ($rows) {
   foreach ($rows as $csvRow) {
       yield $csvRow;
   }
};

foreach ($getRow($rows) as $csvRow) {
    // do something with $csvRow
}
```

So my question is whether using generator in this case actually helps me save memory considering the above code? If not then how should I go about this?

Comment: How is `$rows` generated here? It's _there_ where you have to start with the generator.

Comment: @bwoebi: yes that is there and it is loaded with all rows of certain CSV file.

Comment: @dev02 Well, then, to get a benefit, you'll have to read the CSV file _manually_, _iteratively inside a Generator_.